# Create a new json string from jq output elements

Tags: json, jq

My jq command returns objects in brackets but without comma separators. But I would like to create a new json string from it.

This call finds all elements of `arr` that have a `FooItem` in them and then returns `texts` from the nested array at index `3`:

```
jq '.arr[] | select(index("FooItem")) | .[3].texts'
```

on this json (The original has more elements ):

```
 {
      "arr": [
        [
          "create",
          "w199",
          "FooItem",
          {
            "index": 0,
            "texts": [
              "aBarfoo",
              "avalue"
            ]
          }
        ],
        [
          "create",
          "w200",
          "NoItem",
          {
            "index": 1,
            "val": 5,
            "hearts": 5
          }
        ],
        [
          "create",
          "w200",
          "FooItem",
          {
            "index": 1,
            "texts": [
              "mybarfoo",
              "bValue"
            ]
          }
        ]
    ]
    }
```

returns this output:

```
[
  "aBarfoo",
  "avalue"
]
[
  "mybarfoo",
  "bValue"
]
```

But I'd like to create a new json from these objects that looks like this:

```
{
    "arr": [
        [
            "aBarfoo",
            "avalue"
        ],
        [
            "mybarfoo",
            "bValue"
        ]
    ]
}
```

Can jq do this?

**EDIT**

One more addition: Considering that texts also has strings of zero length, how would you delete those/not have them in the result?

```
"texts": ["",
          "mybarfoo",
          "bValue",
          ""
          ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always embed a stream of (zero or more) JSON entities within some other JSON structure by decorating the stream, that is, in the present case, by wrapping the STREAM as follows:

```
{ arr: [ STREAM ] }
```

In the present case, however, we can also take the view that we are simply editing the original document, and accordingly use a variation of the `map(select(...))` idiom:

```
.arr |= map( select(index("FooItem")) | .[3].texts)
```

This latter approach ensures that the context of the "arr" key is preserved.

### Addendum

To filter out the empty strings, simply add another `map(select(...))`:

```
.arr |= map( select(index("FooItem"))
             | .[3].texts | map(select(length>0)))
```

Comment: Thank you! it works! However I will definitely have to wrap my head around it to understand it.

Comment: Is there a way to rename the array `arr` in the output ?

Comment: Of course. Using the first approach, you just specify the alternative name.  Using the second approach, you could for example write: `.newname = (.arr | map(...)) | del(.arr)`

Comment: Thank you @peak. I had one more final addition, but did not want to ask it in the comments, so I made an edit to the question. Maybe you can help me out one more time.

Comment: Thanks for the addendum!!